# Make event handler ignore children

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

Suppose I have a code similar to what I have below (this is very simplified, but relatively the same idea)

```html
<div>
    <div class="parent" ondragenter="enter()" ondragleave="leave()">
        <div class="child">
            Stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to drag another div on top of the parent div and trigger events for both the ondragenter and ondragleave. This works, but there is an issue. When the item is dragged into the child, the events also fire. Stopping propagation doesn't work, because it simply creates a "hole" where the child element is, and the problem still exists.

Is there any way to completely ignore the child? So I could drag the item in and out of the child and no events fire; they only fire when the item enters and leaves the parent?

I've been stuck on this for more than a week, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the way that I was able to solve my problem was by removing the onleave event altogether. It was what was causing most of the issues.

So, now on onenter, I'm simply checking whether the currentTarget is different than a previously visited currentTarget. If it is, disable the previously visited currentTarget's indicator, and activate the new currentTarget's indicator.

This actually worked better than I had expected, because the indicator stays even if you leave the card, but haven't entered a new card. That way you can always keep track of where you last entered.

Answer (score 2):

Use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), where you only set up the event handler on the outer most parent and handle all events there. In the handler, you test the `event.target` to see what the source element of the event was and only proceed when the element is the one you desire.

Here's a `click` event example:

```js
document.querySelector(".parent").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  console.log("Either the parent or the child was clicked.");

  // Only react if the source of the event was the parent, not the child.
  if(event.target.classList.contains("parent")){
     alert("you clicked on the parent");
  }

});
```

```html
<div>Click on both the parent and the child. Only the parent will perform the desired action.
    <div class="parent">
      I'm the parent
        <div class="child">
            I'm the child
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's definitely getting closer to what I'm needing, but It's still not quite working. What i'm doing is revealing an element when an item is dragged into the parent element and hiding that element when the dragged item leaves the parent element. The children still fire events, and therefore it is difficult to check whether the element should truly be hidden or not.

Comment: The issue i'm running into is when the grabbed item leaves the parent element. I can't figure out how to get my code to differentiate between leaving the actual parent element, or entering into a child element, which registers as leaving the parent element.